# Gradle: task's configuration depends on another task's execution

Tags: gradle

My Gradle build has two task:

- findRevision(type: SvnInfo)
- buildWAR(type: MavenExec, dependsOn: findRevision)

Both tasks are configuration based, but the buildWAR task depends on a project property that is only defined in the execution phase of the findRevision task.

This breaks the process, as Gradle cannot find said property at the time it tries to configure the buildWAR task.

Is there any way to delay binding or configuration until another task has executed?

In this specific case I can make use of the mavenexec method instead of the MavenExec task type, but what should be done in similar scenarios where no alternative method exists?

Comment: Perhaps you could change `findRevision` to `writeRevisionPropertyFile`. Then `buildWAR` could use a property file as input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what configuration option exactly you want to change, you might change it in the execution phase of the task with `buildWAR.doFirst { }`. But generally this is a really bad idea. If you e. g. change something that influences the result of the UP-TO-DATE checks like input files for example, the task might execute though it would not be necessary or even worse do not execute thoug it would be necessary. You can of course make the task always execute to overcome this with `outputs.upToDateWhen { false }`, but there might be other problems and also this way you disable one of Gradles biggest strenghts.

It is a much better idea to redesign your build so that this is not necessary. For example determining the revision at configuration time already. Depending on whether the task needs much time this might be a viable solution or not. Also depending on what you want to do with the revision, you might consider the suggestion of @LanceJava and make your `findRevision` task generate a file with the revision in it that is then packaged into the WAR and used at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I could change the property in doFirst. I'll use it with care given the concerns you raised, but in my case I believe it is necessary.